# Using Ajax to Replace A Page Element Based on an Onclick Event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partials, page-replacement

I'm reformulating this question as I'm understanding the issue better now.

I have an application with four models: Users, Products, Varieties and Seasons.

User
`has_many :seasons

  has_many :products, :through => :seasons

  has_many :varieties, :through => :seasons`

Product
`has_many :seasons

has_many :users, :through => :seasons

has_many :varieties`

Variety
`belongs_to :product

has_many :seasons

has_many :users, :through => :seasons`

Seasons
`belongs_to :product

belongs_to :user

belongs_to :variety`

On the product/show view, I list each variety available for a particular product, and the users who carry that particular product.

When the product/show page first loads, I display all users who carry the product by doing this:

```
<% @product.seasons.each do |c| %>  
  <%= link_to c.user.name, c.user %>  
<% end %>
```

I also list the varieties available for the product by doing this:

```
<% @product.varieties.each do |c| %>  
  <%= link_to_remote variety.name, :url => variety_path(variety) %>  
<% end %>
```

Here's where the Ajax needs to happen.  When I click on a variety name, I want to replace the @product.seasons loop with a @variety.seasons.  I think this should just display only the users who have that particular variety.  So that would look like this:

```
<% @variety.seasons.each do |c| %>  
  <%= link_to c.user.name, c.user %>  
<% end %>
```

I'm getting closer, but I can't get this to work.  Currently, when I click on a variety, nothing happens on the frontend.  In the log, I get this:

```
Processing VarietiesController#4 (for ip at 2009-09-24 16:02:29) [POST]
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"9pDgKrHNbg0aMklsQsGl5BQa34bfr0Ft8Fpbxki3XXw="}
ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to 4. Actions: check_vendor_role, index, and show)
```

The log refers to #4 and refers to 4 as an action.  4 is the variety ID of the item that I clicked on.

Here's my setup:

ProductsController#show
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      @varieties = @product.varieties 
      @users = @product.users

Product/show view
    #Lists the users who have this product

```
<div id="userList">  
  <%= render :partial => "products/users" %>  
</div>  

#Lists the varieties available for this product  

<% @product.varieties.each do |variety| %>  
  <%= link_to_remote variety.name, :url => variety_path(variety) %>  
<% end %>
```

VarietiesController#show.

```
  def show
   @variety = Variety.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml  { render :xml => @variety}
      format.js
    end
  end
```

varieties/show.js.rjs
    @page.replace_html "userList", :partial => "products/users", :collection => @variety.users

So, currently, the page is rendering and displaying the proper html and data.  But the onclick is not functioning.  When I click a variety, the the app does not properly process the request and the user list does not change.

#### Update

Response to Anatoliy's comment:

I'm not sure exactly what route needs to be added.  I tried adding the following, but the result was the same as before:

map.resources :varieties, :member => { :show => :get }

Could you be more specific about what member route should be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stated in the comments (which should be listed as an answer):

Add :method => :get to your link_to_remote call to use the correct HTTP verb for "show" against that URL.

Comment: Yes!  This was the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<div id="userList">  shoul be <div id="users">

Comment: That was a typo in my question.  I fixed it.  Any other ideas?

Comment: In config/routes.rb should be declared appropriate action in :member section of controller (to avoid error UnknownAction No action responded to 4.)

Comment: I added an update to follow up on this.  I'm not sure exactly what route you're thinking should be added.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Ajax uses POST by default, but your routes expects GET, you shoud fix link like that: :html => { :method => :get } (i'm not shure syntax, but basically idea)